# TWAIN/WIA implementation for JAVA

Tags: java, 64-bit, wia, twain, image-scanner

I am working on an application(Java Applet) that interacts with scanner. I understand I need a Twain library or WIA library to make it work in windows. But I am not sure what are the differences of two? I am trying to use this library:

http://thorntonzone.com/manuals/Compression/Fax,%20IBM%20MMR/MMSC/mmsc/uk/co/mmscomputing/device/twain/index.html

JAR file link is broken so I got it from here.
http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/plugins/twain-scan.html

And DLLs from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-dsm/?source=dlp

But, it does not detect the source. Here is the error log:

http://pastebin.com/cB9gL0ip

I am on 64bit machine. Anybody had any success?

TWAIN specification is too long to follow and I haven't found any resources on WIA implementation.

Any help/pointers/resources is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might like to check out [Morena 7](http://www.gnome.sk/Morena/morena.html).  I've used the Twain API in the past and it was very nice.  I've seen the WIA implementation working (beta) and it seemed to work just fine

Comment: I am looking for a free solution. My question was edited to remove that line.

Comment: Personally, I've never found a free twain solution that worked well and I've never seen a WIA solution at all, but that's me

Comment: mmsc library works great for SANE, it is just the twain that is not working for me. I haven't seen WIA solution either. I found another post complaining the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089236/twain-device-scanner-control-in-java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Use the same bit mode

For twain device control in java, **all components need to be in the same mode.** i.e. the JRE, Twain DSM (Source Manager), and the Twain driver (Scanner driver) **all need to be 32-bit or all 64-bit.** No mixing.

The default installation of 64-bit Windows contains the 32-bit mode of Twain DSM. And you say you've downloaded the 64-bit DSM.  It's likely that the scanner's driver is 32-bit and that is why it cannot be found.

You have 2 options:

### Keep it all 64-bit.

- Use the 64-bit TWAINDSM.DLL.
- Make sure your JRE/JDK is 64-bit.
- Make sure your scanner has a 64-bit driver.

My scanner doesn't have a 64-bit driver available, but I tested a 64-bit configuration using a 64-bit "virtual scanner" and it worked.

### Keep it all 32-bit (recommended)

- Use the 32-bit TWAINDSM.DLL.
- Make sure your JRE/JDK is 32-bit.
- Use the scanner's 32-bit driver (probably default).

You can download 32 and 64 bit [twain virtual scanners](http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-samples/files/TWAIN%202%20Sample%20Application/) here.

Note: I mention the JDK because if you're running the code from an IDE it may be pointing to a different JRE to to the system default. True story, happened to me.

Comment: Jonathan, it was bit mode issue. I took me two days to understand the issue. I just had to change my IDE point to 32bit JRE. Thank you!!