# How to implement Scanner in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, image-scanner

I want to implement java code to scan documents from Scanner device through JavaFX. I am not getting any hint to perform such task. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For OCR scanning there is the TWAIN protocol to control devices. Look what some Linux applications do.

Comment: I need code pattern if u have any or link..

Comment: Maybe this helps
[twain and java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893046/twain-wia-implementation-for-java/15993050#15993050

Answer (score 0):

There is no native support for external devices like scanners in Java.  You need to use a 3rd party library of some kind.  The most popular choices are

- [JTwain](http://www.asprise.com/product/jtwain/) (Windows)
- [Morena](http://www.gnome.sk/Twain/jtp.html) (Multi-OS)
- [JSANE](http://asprise.com/product/jsane/index.php) (*nix)